# iOS9 develop, Typedef redefinition with different types

Tags: ios, swift, enums

I import an objective c framework into my project via Cocoapods. In the framework, a header defines an enum named Action.

```
typedef enum : uint16_t {
    Action_1                  = 0,
    Action_2                   = 1
} ACTION //FileA.h
```

In my bridging-Header.h file , I import this header file by:

```
#import <TheFramework/FileA.h>
```

When I compile the apps, the complier comes the error:

......./FileA.h:24:3: error: typedef redefinition with different types ('enum ACTION' vs 'enum ACTION')
} ACTION;
  ^
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator9.3.sdk/usr/include/search.h:23:3: note: previous definition is here
} ACTION;

Since I cannot modify the source code of my framework, how can I handle this problem

Comment: Do you need that header? Since this is a plain C `enum`, you should be able to just define two constants `let action1: UInt16 = 0` and `let action2: UInt16 = 1` and use them instead of the original enum. It's not an ideal solution but if the pod ignores Apple naming guidelines, that's probably your best option.

Comment: Yes , I need that header since it contains necessary methods definition. I think the problem is the enum definition is conflict with the system enum....

Comment: Yes, it doesn't follow Obj-C naming conventions which will definitely be a problem if there is already the same identifier.

Comment: You can wrap your library into custom Obj-C wrappers and then import only the wrappers to Swift.

Comment: Yes,finally,I solved the problem by wrapping the library